# jQuery click jumping to top of page on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a footer that basically when you click on a link it opens a draw style effect to show more links. The problem I have when I click on the link it jumps to the top of the page in Safari (tested on iPhone and iPad) (Chrome works fine).

I have added the following to the jQuery:

```
jQuery('#click').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do something
    return false;
});
```

However this has not fixed the issue.

The full code is here on codepen: https://codepen.io/tcfmark/pen/VxWxxa

**UPDATE:** It works fine on an iPad 2 in Safari on iOS 7 but not on iPhone using Safari or Chrome iOS 11?

If anyone can take a look where I'm going wrong it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving javascript aside, how about using the new `details/summary` element.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

details{
  text-align: center;
}

details div{
  display: flex;
  
}

details div > div{
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary></summary>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: Using Details / Summary the page still goes to the top on Safari.